# Save Checkbox State and Update Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am stucked with an idea I want to implement into one of my projects, and I need some help from the best. :)

**What I have**

[Even Not done! http://img299.imageshack.us/img299/4142/screenshot20100727at185.png](http://img299.imageshack.us/img299/4142/screenshot20100727at185.png)

[Event Done http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/4142/screenshot20100727at185.png](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/4142/screenshot20100727at185.png)

In the first image I pull some info from my DB and display that info and also a button do Edit/Remove that Even and a Checkbox that should be checked in case of the Event is finished/done.

In the second image, when the checkbox is checked that div turn green and the button goes away (hidden).

**What I want**

It's a bit hard to explain, but i'll try my best.

When an user checks that checkbox, It will update the field "done" in the DB of that Event with the value 1.

After this, every time I check these events, they should save their state (if it's done or not). They should keep just like the second image if the field "done" in the DB is 1.

**Question**

How can I accomplish this? Can someone give me some tips?

Much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: You do not need to include [Bracketed Text] in your question title.  That's what tags are for.

Comment: Sorry Charles. Thanks for editing my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initiate the ajax call as stated above to update the database value to done:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'script_to_update_db',
    data:({done:'true'}),
    async:false,
    success:function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Then, when the page is loaded, you need to check if the done value is set in the database, if it is, trigger your function that removes the button and makes the div turn green.  How you do all of this really depends on how your code is set up.  Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks wowo_999. I have some questions, in your script you are sending by POST or GET the data? In the script where I update the DB, how can I get the value sent by ajax, using your example?

I'm fairly new to ajax/jquery, so I have some stupid questions. I also read the documentation, but some doubts still remain.

Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  First, the default for the jquery ajax method is GET however, this can be overridden by specifying type:'POST' as a parameter.  From there, in php you can access it via $_REQUEST['done'], or $_GET['done'], or if you change it to post $_POST['done']

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to fire off an ajax request to your server to tell it to update the database.  I would check out jQuery's excellent ajax library. http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/  You could also use jquery's change event handler to trigger the ajax request http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I've already read the ajax integration with jQuery. I dunno how can I pass the checked status from one page to the one I have into url:.

How can I do this? Thanks.